# How to make Internet Explorer ActiveX dialog visible

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, activex

I have an ActiveX control written in C# which operates a scanner from the browser using WIA. Everything works fine except the WIA CommonDialog pops under the browser window. How can I get it to show up on top of the browser?

```
wiaDialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
wiaImage = wiaDialog.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,  WiaImageIntent.UnspecifiedIntent, WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality,                               wiaFormatJPEG, false, false, false);
```

[Edit]

Thanks very much to Noseratio for putting me onto the right track. The suggestion to use BringWindowToTop invoked via a timer before popping up the dialog does not quite work. Instead the function to use is SetForegroundWindow. The code is as follows (invoked from a System.Timer.Timer prior to opening the scan dialog):

```
public static void scanDialogToTop(Object caller, EventArgs theArgs) {  
    scanner.theTimer.Stop();  
    foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses()) {  
        if (p.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("Scan using")) {  
            SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);  
            break;  
        }  
     }  
}
```

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201728/bringwindowtotop-is-not-working-even-if-i-get-the-handle-to-class-window) for a more complete discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like you can specify a parent window for `ShowAcquireImage`. If the caption of the popup window is static, you could use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the popup's handle. If `ShowAcquireImage` is a blocking call (doesn't return until the popup window is closed), before calling it you'd need to setup a timer and call `FindWindow` upon a timer event. I also suspect the WIA popup is created on a different thread (you could check that with Spy++). If that's the case, you could use the [following hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879890/understanding-attachthreadinput-detaching-lose-focus/18052274#18052274) to give the WIA popup window focus. Otherwise you just do [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).